# Exchange Server 2010 with Dynamic IP setup - dyndns service

Tags: exchange, dynamic-ip

Novice DNS and Exchange user here. I've got a lab for a mail server - MS Exchange 2010.

So here's the setup and scenario:

```
Server IP - 192.168.13.1 (DNS /AD/MS EXCHANGE 2010)
ROUTER IP - 192.168.13.2
```

DYNDNS Personal domain - mydomain.com

#### DNS Records

```
   x.x.x.x mydomain.com        - A record (public IP address added in dyndns update client)
   x.x.x.x mail.mydomain.com   - A record (same as above)
           5 mail.mydomain.com - MX record pointed to mydomain.com
           www.mydomain.com    - CNAME
```

MODEM ROUTER connected via ISP with FIBER PPOE Dynamic IP as usual.

- configured ddns service with my account
- configured with port forwarding PORTS for the http (80) and MAIL (25) to Server
  (192.168.13.1)

Exchange Server is working perfectly internally configuration is as follows

- host.mydomain.com - server name for physical and incoming and outgoing

#### DNS Server Records

```
   192.168.13.1 mydomain.com        - A record / NS Record
   192.168.13.1 mail.mydomain.com   - A record (same as above)
              5 mail.mydomain.com   - MX record pointed to mydomain.com
```

#### Question:

Besides the configuration for the dyndns I made above. How can I make this mail server work with externally. I have tried a lot configuration I got from a lot of forums but I can't seem to make it work.

What is the proper configuration and setup to make this external live access?

Any suggestions and recommendations are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Exchange to accept email for "mydomain.com" then you'll need to create an Accepted Domain in the Exchange Management Console or the Exchange Management Shell for "mydomain.com" and you'll need to add "mydomain.com" to your E-mail Address Policy.

Comment: Thanks joeqwerty for the help got bit busy lateley. I will do that and see hat happens. Thanks again